# Import currently installed programs in OneGet

Tags: windows, powershell, package-managers, oneget

I would like to start using OneGet for installing programs in windows. However, I would rather not have to go through and uninstall my current programs just so that i can use them with OneGet.

Does OneGet automatically import installed programs and if not is there any kind of tool i can use to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OneGet does not support such a functionality and so the answer is you cannot do this.

However if you are interested in this please do leave a feedback at https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell The team periodically reviews feedback and considers top asks (*Disclaimer: there is no promise)*